# Why does this MD5 algorithm return what seems to be a memory location and not a hash?

Tags: c, hash, md5

I am trying to wrap my head around the Brad Conte MD5 algorithm.

You can get it here: https://github.com/B-Con/crypto-algorithms
(md5.c, md5.h, md5_test.c)

Also an example of generating a hash here: http://bradconte.com/files/projects/code/md5_example.c

The example says it should be printing the hashes:

```
d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e
900150983cd24fb0d6963f7d28e17f72
d174ab98d277d9f5a5611c2c9f419d9f
```

But for me it prints:

```
ffffffd41dffffff8cffffffd9ffffff8f00ffffffb204ffffffe9ffffff8009ffffff98ffffffe    cfffffff8427e
ffffff900150ffffff983cffffffd24fffffffb0ffffffd6ffffff963f7d28ffffffe17f72
ffffffd174ffffffabffffff98ffffffd277ffffffd9fffffff5ffffffa5611c2cffffff9f41ffffff9dffffff9f
```

These seems like memory addresses and not hashes to me?

I'm new to both C and MD5, so I might be doing something wrong - but I find it weird that the example does not print what the description says it should.

Would someone care to check this out?

Comment: Add the [mcve] code into the question.

Comment: Looks like 16-bit values sign-extended to 32-bit - probably using `int16_t` somewhere instead of `uint16_t`?

Answer (score 3):

The `printf` converts a `char` to an `int`. The result depends on whether a `char` is signed or not (and thus gets sign-extended in your case).

Are you sure you want to use a crypto package that makes such mistakes?

Comment: Its for a school assignment, and i have been told to use it - with no further explanation.

Comment: Is there anything i can do to fix it?

Comment: You could convert the value to unsigned first, perhaps `(int)((unsigned char)hash[idx])`, and display that.

Comment: Thanks, now its a hash. But it generates a different hash for the same file every time i run it. Isnt the same file supposed to have the same sum?

Comment: Yes, the general idea is to verify the file by recomputing the hash and see that is hasn't changed. Perhaps you should ask a new question where you show your code with a sample file and the results you get?